# Problem installing ppa webupd8team/java

Tags: software-installation, ppa, java

I can't install Java in elementary. I tried to install it in my computer:

```
$ sudo add/apt/repository ppa>webupd8team/java

bash: webupd8team/java: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all, write in english please, if you want anyone except those who understand your language to help you. Second, in order to encourage people to help you or respond, you need at least a well structured and detailed post. Until then, I downvote.

Comment: I thought I had installed this update also, and yet my machine ignored java8. I think it may be due to python3 that you can't install some of the dependencies: sudo apt install software-properties-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done
Package software-properties-common is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Answer (score 1):

Add the PPA by doing the following:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt update
```

This (1) lets you install PPAs on elementary Loki, (2) adds the PPA you want, and (3) update your records. Then you can install the package you were originally after.